# Designing a PCB with variable-sized component alternatives

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, fritzing

I'd like to get a little PCB manufactured with a basic circuit that I can populate with components of various sizes. E.g. have a place where any of a range of possible capacitor sizes could go. So I would have a chain of leads, like this, for example, where depending on size, I would use a closer or further-apart lead for the component in question:

```
---O-O-O O---
```

I'm finding it difficult to convince KiCad or Fritzing to let me do that. They seem to think that any component has exacly one size, and I can't find an "empty lead" part to add either.

Any advice how to best go about this?

Comment: 1) Put extra capacitors on the schematic, value "DNF" (Do Not Fit) if the rule checking is lax enough to let you put the footprints on top of each other. Or, 2) create your own footprints with all the extra pads.

Comment: I agree with option 1 of Brian. This is the correct way to go about this. Everything else is a bodge that will bite you in the long term (Will you remember 2 or 3 years down the line what parts could fit without this being made clear in the schematic/BOM?)
I would however advise against overlapping footprint pads as it will make soldering harder and less reliable (worst case can even lead to shorts). A board with such a high degree of part selection flexibility will simply need to trade it for space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make double and triple footprints in KiCAD quite regularly and it works out quite well.  You need to be careful about production constraints (avoid holes in SMD pads, etc), but KiCAD does allow you to do what you want.

There are several ways to go about it:

- Superpose all the footprints one on top of the other.  You need to ignore the specific DRC errors about overlapping courtyards, and sometimes place holes very precisely in the same location.
- Create a specific footprint.  In your example, you would give the same PAD index number for a group of PADs.  Once you do your PCB layout, the router will request you to add the traces between the PADs that have the same indexes.  So you still have some freedom on how you want to route this.

Here is an example where I superpose two different rectifying bridges.  The center is slightly different so that the PADs do not superpose:

[image: Two superposed diode bridges]

[image: The 3D view, with only one bridge shown, you can see two PADS of the other bridge under it]

Here is an example where I can put one out of two fuse holders using a single footprint:

[image: Footprint for two fuse holders]

And another case where I superposed two RJ45 connectors - one SMD and one THT - the "holes" are superposed:

[image: Superposed MAGJACK footprints]

Answer (score 3):

while I remember there being a few more flexible footprints (especially, the "hand soldering" SMD footprints), this simply screams "you want something oddly specific, so, go and design your own footprint". It's surprisingly easy!

If you want, you can also do the nice FOSS thing and then upstream your new footprint to the kicad-library.

Comment: I need to disappoint you here. A footprint like this violates the rules of the official lib and would never be accepted. (A footprint must represent one package and be made in accordance to manufacturer suggestions or an industry standard.)

Comment: The correct way of doing this is having all different options for part selection in the schematic/BOM and mark all but the selected one as DNF. Then place all footprints next to each other while avoiding pads to overlap as that would negatively impact the solder process. (The trade of is between part selection flexibility against board space)

Comment: @RenePöschl you're doing the opposite of disappointing! You're giving exactly the information OP needs. I'd argue that your comments, as valuable as they are here, would be even better as a competing answer – which I'd upvote!

Comment: @RenePöschl "violates the rules of the official lib and would never be accepted" Umm... accepted by whom? I understand what you are saying, but manufacturer's suggested layout is just that - a suggestion. In reality there are situations when different footprint is beneficial. "hand soldering" mentioned above is one example (BTW, it is part of "official" library). Specific thermal requirements is another. Or small modification of SMD choke footprint allowing mounting of a resistor jumper instead. There are countless examples like that and I see nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @Maple I'm not involved with maintaining the kicad library, but I maintain a relatively medium- to large-sized FOSS project: Accepted by the people having to watch over the quality of the library. They set up a relatively extensive document, and some footprints simply aren't allowed by that – for reasons of quality assurance, even if these footprints look reliable. A lot of "legacy exception" rules apply to such projects – if I was to kick out all legacy code that doesn't meet my modern standards, my project's C++ code base would be looking a lot emptier than it does :)

Comment: @Maple but your concern is pretty valid: you might want to raise it with the community and maintainers of kicad-library. I'd argue that this isn't the right place to discuss the standards that that community set itself. Contribute – and ye shall have influence.

Comment: @Maple We deliberatly threw out these legacy stuff with version 5. (We threw out all old 3d models for example as they do no longer fit the new workflow that requires them to be scaled correctly for the step export. We also threw out all badly made footprints for whom we could not find documentation on how to make them better. If we missed some let us know such that we can throw these out as well.) Oh and we can do that because footprints are included in the project files of projects that require them as well as in the old downloads (see it similar to the python2 vs python3 change)

Comment: @Maple and regarding the hand solder footprints: yes we have a few of them still in the lib. But we will not add new ones. (The ones we have are in there because we do not want people to complain too much. And it is limited to two terminal chip packages and DIP packages so not that bad. However we might throw these out with v6 in favor of offering multiple IPC density levels.)

Comment: @RenePöschl I understand the concept of "developer's pride" very well, been there myself many times. The problem, however, is that developers often forget their best in the world design is supposed to work for the users, not the other way around. In case of KiCad, people are making their own footprints to better fit the application, not to match the expectation of KiCad developers, or be approved by them. As long as manufacturing houses are OK with them they are perfectly valid, IMHO.

Comment: @Maple I'm really really really not in favor of claiming this has anything to do with pride. Quite on the contrary! I've deleted lots of lines of code that I wrote myself from community projects I maintain – because they simply didn't fit the way we agreed on moving forward. It always hurts to abandon legacy, most developers *are* power users. If these agree that there are good and bad ways, and they only support good ways in a library, then there's often a reason for that. In this case the reasons seem pretty clear to me. Just because something *can* be done, you really shouldn't assume it

Comment: @Maple to be an idea that's good, and especially not good enough to be supported and shipped by your community-driven FOSS project. With all due respect, if you really need a footprint that isn't a good idea in the larger scheme of things to have, but that fits your specific use case,then I don't see how you're expecting *maintainers* of high-quality libraries to include these. "Valid" isn't a good category here: A footprint that's just a blob of solder is "valid". A "useful component in a library of parts that a community can support" is the important aspect here.Kicad sets its own standards.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Where did you get that "you're expecting maintainers of high-quality libraries to include these" from? I NEVER expected anything like that. All I am saying is that PCB designers should have an option to make their own footprints according to application requirements. Take a look at Torex XCL223 modules, for example. Their recommended layout is 15x15mm, the demo board is 70x70mm, and the chip itself is 2.3x1.5mm. This is a case where application's thermal requirements dictate the footprint (you cannot just use copper pour here, due to complexity of the layout)

Comment: @Maple sure! But you applied the anecdotal circumstance that "developers often forget their best work in the world design is supposed to work for the users", and that's really the goal, but that this goal isn't universally applicable has nothing to do with "developer's pride", which you set causally link to that.

Comment: @Maple a good library can't meet everyone's requirements. That's logically impossible. A good footprint for some application can't work for another. Is that a reason to include both? Not really, if either of them belongs in the category of "tempting, but dangerous, and also extremely special case". Sure, having a library of components with thermally expanded planes would be great. But usually, these footprints should have no place in a "standard" library. And I find it very self-evident that this is the case here: Imagine the mayhem on design quality and all the additional RF problems one

Comment: would incur if people started using multi-distance two-pin through-hole footprints by default, instead of researching a reasonable BOM between schematic and layout step. Sure, cases where having such a footprint is good exist, and OP probably has one of these, but NOT having that footprint in the default library is a very solid choice, that I fully understand. GNU Radio has an extensive block library, and I still reject the idea of some blocks being added, because they *mathematically* do the wrong thing, even if they work for some special corner case.

Comment: @Maple and then there's the problem with *maintainability* and *community sustainability* attached to this. Assume you have  footprint of questionable quality, that especially beginner users will be using (and that this usage is often an effect of bad design methodology). That can lead to a lot of new user frustration, that just hits later, or to a lot of mailing list and bug tracker traffic, that simply binds time that people are willing to volunteer, in which they could have been writing *useful* code. A maintainer needs to tell people off at times about features they want, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That comment was not intended as sarcasm, merely an observation from 25+ years in IT. It was a reply to "violates the rules of official lib" statement and was meant to say that rules of official lib should not ultimately define application-specific design. Once again, **I do not expect these application-specific footprints to be included into standard library,** nor did I ever suggest this in my comments above.

Comment: @Maple I'm not really sure where I misunderstood you, then! I didn't think that was sarcasm, so I directly addressed it, because yes, there's a good reason that we agree on that some footprints wouldn't be included. But: Rene never said that you shouldn't design it yourself, he just said it then wouldn't be integrated in the library.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmm... looking back, it seems the misunderstanding was on my part. I missed "upstream" word in your post, which triggered Rene's reply. So all this long discussion was one big chain of misunderstanding. My apologies.

Comment: @Maple no apologies needed, because this was also a good discussion, nevertheless :)

Answer (score 1):

I generally would not suggest combining multiple components into one footprint/symbol. This will hide a lot of information from a reader of the schematic. It is much better to have one symbol per possible alternative in the schematic (connected in parallel). This allows you to create a BOM for every variation as required. (This could lead to false positive ERC errors/warnings depending on how the symbols are designed. Sadly there is no "do not show this one message in the future" option in KiCad.)

You can then overlap the footprints as needed in pcbnew, but make sure not to overlap pads as this can create trouble with soldering. There simply is a tradeoff between component selection flexibility and board size. (This restriction also applies when making a single footprint for all possible components.)

Another benefit to having one symbol/footprint per possible combination is that you are still get one centroid per possible part in the pos file which is required for automated manufacturing. Meaning combining different options within a footprint will likely restrict your options for automated manufacturing. (You never know if you might not in some future want to go this route for some of your projects.)

Comment: "you are still get one centroid per possible part in the pos file which is required for automated manufacturing". Carefully prepared footprint should not create any problems for manufacturing house, I think. For example I recently made a board with 3-pad soldering jumper made by adding a third pad to standard 0603 resistor footprint. The center was left between NC contacts and component was added to BOM as 0603 jumper. The assembly shop had no problems with this whatsoever.

Comment: A solderjumper is a bit different though. It does not require something to be placed by the pick and place machine. (And if you used a 0ohm 0603 resistor then you need to have two footprints, one with placed on position 1 with the center being aligned with that and one with position 2. Or you need to have a symbol that indicates where the resitor will be placed and connect it such that it agrees with that. Will save you one footprint but that one still needs the centriod to agree with one of the two possible positions)

Comment: And of course you can still use a pick and place machine with the centroid (of the footprint) being not aligned with the pick and place center of the component. But it will make programming the machine harder and could mean that your manufacturer will charge extra or flat out refuse to take on the job.

Comment: Since the symbol can be easily rotated and/or mirrored, and in case of a jumper the pin numbering makes no difference whatsoever, I do not need two symbols or footprints. A third pad is added without paste layer and center is left between first two pads, so as far as manufacturing house is concerned, they are working with simple 2-pad 0603 component. No problem for pick and place and all the rotation/positioning data is generated properly.

Comment: Here is another example - I had to make sure the board can accommodate different DC-DC modules, depending on installation requirements (hand-soldered _after_ manufacturing). All 24 modules with compatible footprints had different values for external decoupling caps and EMI filters. Unlike caps, wirewound chokes have vastly different footprints even within one manufacturer. So I went through literally hundreds of datasheets collecting footprint dimensions, then calculated one footprint that fits any one of them.

Comment: Hand population does not depend on centroid data so i fail to see how this adds to your claim about this being unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Fritzing using a 1 x *n* pin header component to add the *n* extra holes (a 1-pin header is your 'empty lead component'). Place the header on the PCB layout first, place the copper tracks as you want them, then go back to the schematic view and tidy up there. You'll probably want to hide the silkscreen for the header.

This won't leave you with a fully professional looking schematic, but if you needed that you wouldn't be using Fritzing. It should achieve what you need on the PCB though.